# What's the simplest way to write this CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What's the simplest way to write a CSS selector that matches

```
#id.X .X a
```

for all `X`?

Currently I'm manually specifying it for each `X` I need, however it'd be much nicer to write a blanket statement and not have to edit the css each time I add a new `X`.

Edit: The trimmed HTML this is for:

```
<div id="id" class="X">
<ul>
<li class="projects">...</li>
<li class="music">...</li>
<li class="resume">...</li>
<li class="contact">...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Where X is one of `projects`, `music`, etc. The purpose of having the class in the enclosing `div` be equal to the class of one of the subobjects is to apply some style to one of the particular list elements. The reason I want to do it this way rather than having something like an `active` class is that it makes my template files much more readable.

Comment: If you have equal classes for ancestor and descendant, then your structure is likely nonoptimal. Post an example of your real code and describe your real goal. Based on your current example, `.X A` selector could be enough.

Comment: @j08691 HTML posted with explanation, sorry for the delay.

Comment: So your selector you posted is really: `#id.X .Y a` (ie: the container class and child class aren't the same)? In that case, isn't `#id.class a {...}` sufficient? No need to be overly specific, just slows things down.

Comment: @steveax Sorry when I was trimming the HTML I messed up the hierarchy, edited..

Comment: @jli OK, so this should do the trick: `#id .class a {...}`

Comment: @steveax I don't think you quite understand what I'm trying to do here. I just want to match subelements of `#id` with class equal to the class of the parent `ul`. So in the case of `X=='projects'`, only `#id li.projects` should match.

Comment: @jli you're correct, I don't understand. The HTML you posted does not match what your original selector shows (`#id.X .X a`). Perhaps you meant this? `#id .X .X a` (note the space, if the space is not there, that selector matches this: `<div id="id" class="X">`

Comment: @steveax You're also correct, I messed up in my question. I _did_ actually mean to have `<div id="id" class="X">`. I've fixed it another way though, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by not trying to do this with CSS alone. Instead I modified the code to use an `active` class and then just matched that. It made my templating more complicated, but in the end it's a better solution.

To be clear, I now have something like:

```
<div id="id">
<ul>
<li class="active">...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If it ain't broke (by using an `active` class)... don't fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Current CSS does not provide means to avoid enumeration of all parent/child-class combinations in your case. So either your template should be more complicated while CSS is less complicated, or vice versa. Marking current element with class like `active` or `cur` is most universal and widely used solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a naming pattern so that the class starts with, contains, or ends with a certain string, you could use the attribute selectors

**Starts with**

```
#id[class^="foo"] *[class^="foo"] a { color: red; }
```

**Contains**

```
#id[class*="foo"] *[class*="foo"] a { color: red; }
```

**Ends with**

```
#id[class$="foo"] *[class$="foo"] a { color: red; }
```

Fiddle using starts with: http://jsfiddle.net/TufaD/

An alternate strategy would be to assign a common class to all the elements you wish to style that way.

Comment: This doesn't play well with multiple classes though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a `class` that is a child of the same `class` as the basis for the target, I think you have three options, the ***first*** being the method you are using.

The ***second*** would be adding some extra into the HTML (a second class on the second object *only when it is nested*) like so:

**CSS**

```
.nestedA a {... blah ...}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="id" class="X"><div class="X nestedA"><a></a></div></div>
```

So it shrinks your CSS, but expands your HTML, requiring you to code it (knowing it is nested, either by hand or by javascript detection).

The ***third*** is to prefix any classes that you intend this for and use the attribute start selector (IE8+ with DOCTYPE) like so (note the beginning portion must be separated by a hyphen):

**CSS**

```
.na-X {... X class blah ...}
[class|=na] [class|=na] a {... blah ...}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="id" class="na-X"><div class="na-X"><a></a></div></div>
```